# Hooking Stack Overflow up to Chime caused me to gain the enthusiast badge

Tags: support, badges

I hooked up StackOverflow to Chime and it gave me the badge, presumably because Chime visited the site invisibly for me. Can this badge be removed from my profile somehow? I don't want it unless I've earned it.

Comment: Such a funny request. You must be the only one here asking to remove a badge !

Comment: Hmm.. If you don't mind, I am ready to borrow the badge.. :)

Comment: How will you know when you've "actually" earned it?

Comment: http://chimeapp.com/ btw.

Answer (score 11):

Nope; you have it now. Removing the badge wouldn't do much good, since you still have 30 consecutive access days, so the badge would be automatically reawarded.

You're right though, this shouldn't really count, and it won't in the future (so you won't get the Fanatic badge this way). But the Enthusiast badge you get to keep. After all you were enthusiastic enough to make us aware of this :)

Comment: "*so you won't get the Fanatic badge this way*" because you are know blocking Chime or something like this?

Comment: No, we just don't count the requests to get your inbox contents (which is what Chime polls, and probably other browser extensions as well) as a site access for the badge anymore.